# jQuery tooltip re-opens on window focus

Tags: tooltip

I have the following problem with jQuery (1.10.3) tooltip plugin.

I have several links like

```
<a target="_blank" class="tooltip_top_studios">Link1</a>
```

and jquery code:

```
$(".tooltip_top_studios").tooltip({
    tooltipClass:'ui-tooltip',
    position: { my: "left+15 top", at: "right center" },
    show: { effect: "fadeIn", delay: 300},

    content: function() {
       var img_src = $(this).attr('rel');
       var html =  "<h1 style='color:#d4dce8;margin-bottom:7px;'>" 
          + $(this).attr('title') + "</h1>" + "<span style='font-weight:bold;font-size:10px;margin-bottom:7px;padding:0;display:block;'>"  
          + $(this).attr('name') + "</span><img width=280 src='" + img_src + "' /> ";

        return html;
     },
});
```

The problem is that when I click the link, tooltip appears without any problem and new tab with link's URLopens, but when I return to the first page tooltip appears again. I have to click somewhere in page to close it.

Maybe there is a way to close all tooltips on window focus automatically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. The problem caused because then I return on page focus on tooltip anchore was not removed automaticaly, so tooltip executed again.
This code remove focus from all a tags and worked fine :

```
$(window).focus(function() {
$('a').focus(function() {
    this.blur();
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First:

I found that, if you return a null value into the content function, the tooltip will not be shown.

The second point:

You can find elements into html document using:

```
 document.elementsFromPoint
```

And you have access to the event was fired into the context of content function.

Then the workaround is something like that:

```
$( "body" ).tooltip({
        items: "[data-title]",
        content: function() {                
            if (document.elementsFromPoint(event.pageX,event.pageY).indexOf(this) === -1)
                return null;
            var title = $(this).data("title");                
            return title;
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "fadeOut"
        }
    });
```